# fabricjs or slimerjs, "all objects displayed" event?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, phantomjs, fabricjs

I'm using slimerjs to render some html files. Each file contains a JSON string that gets loaded with a call to

```
fabricjsCanvas.loadFromJson(jsonString, fabricjsCanvas.renderAll.bind(fabricjsCanvas));
```

This is where I open my page

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the page!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        page.render(output);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

As you can see I had to set a timeout after which slimerjs closes the page saving what's on it. I really don't like this solution, coz I need to render multiple pages, some of them are very small, and could take less than 200 milliseconds, others are huge and could take more than 5000, so this is just bad for perfomances and isn't even a "safe solution" against page taking a long time to render. I tryid putting a console.log at the end of canvas.renderAll call and then add this piece of code to my slimerjs script

```
 page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    page.render(output);
    phantom.exit();
};page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

I hoped that this would have helped but nothing really changed, the reanderAll finishes before all objects are displayed. 
Is there some event I can catch, or something else I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. First of all I changed my html template,since I only need to render per page i used a StaticCanvas instead of a normal canvas. Since a static canvas only has 2 frames to render(the top one and the secondary container, at least this is what I've learned in my experience) I added an event lister on after:render event, so after the second frame has been rendered I print a console message, at this point the page.onConsoleMessage gets called and closes the phantom process. 
In this way I don't need to allow a standard amount of time that could be too much (loosing perfomances) or not enough (and the image would result blank). 
this is the script in my html template

```
 var framesRendered = 0;
    var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas', {width: {{width}}, height: {{height}} });
    canvas.setZoom({{{zoom}}});
    canvas.on('after:render', function() {
        if(framesRendered == 1)
            console.log('render complete');
        else framesRendered++;
    });
    canvas.loadFromJSON({{{data}}}, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function (o, object) {
        if (object.type === 'picturebox' && object.filters.length) {
            object.applyFilters(function () {
                canvas.renderAll();
            });
        }
    });
```

and this is my slimerjs script

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(){
    page.render(output);
    phantom.exit();
};
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

I'll leave this one here in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback **page.onLoadFinished()**.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status, url, isFrame) {
    console.log('Loading of '+url+' is a '+ status);
    page.render();
};
```

This function run after full upload page

Comment: I tried using onLoadFinished, but when this event is fired the canvas still hasn't finished drawing itself on the page.